# Cloning a SQL Server Virtual Machine with TDE

Tags: sql-server, transparent-data-encryption, virtualisation

When a virtual machine with a SQL Server database that uses TDE is copied or cloned, will the database be readable on the new instance?

Comment: For cloning it should work, i don't understand what copied means here.

Comment: @Shanky - same thing, I guess. VMWare distinguishes between "copying" and "moving" and I was curious if either would affect the machine key or other "unique" things on the machine..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cloning or copying a VM should **not** make a database using TDE unreadable or unavailable on the new cloned VM.

If you check the [Move a TDE Protected Database to Another SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/move-a-tde-protected-database-to-another-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) doc, which by the way is not specifically what you're trying to do, but lists the restrictions that could cause a TDE database unable to be decrypted on a different server, you'll see that none of the [Limitations and Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/move-a-tde-protected-database-to-another-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#Restrictions) rules are broken when copying or cloning a VM.

Every "piece" needed to decrypt the database is going to be copied along with the VM and everything shall be at the same place within the new VM.